# Import config variables

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to set up firebase service worker for both test and production environments and their configs are different. When I deploy my project, I have a jenkins script that copies either `firebase.test.config.js` or `firebase.prod.config.js` to another file `library/firebase.config.js`.

The `library/firebase.config.js` file ends up looking like this:

```
export var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSy....6Vs8zAa2DM",
  authDomain: "app-test.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://app-test.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "app-test",
  storageBucket: "app-test.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "9160...4111",
  appId: "1:91603....0859d93ba",
  measurementId: "G-4...V64"
};

export default {
  firebaseConfig
}
```

I want to import this config variable to my firebase service worker file `firebase-messaging-sw.js`. But this file sits at the root of the entire project and I'm getting an error when I'm trying to import `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseConfig = require('./library/firebase.config.js');

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Comment: That error message means that `firebase-messaging-sw.js` is not an ES6 module, and not able to use `import`/`export` syntax. Use `require()` instead. This has nothing to do with the path (or at best, that your transpiler doesn't catch it).

Comment: Don't default-export an object literal.

Comment: @Bergi The service worker is a simple js file and I'm getting an error `require is not defined`.

Comment: Is this is a clientside script, in a `<script>` tag on an html page? What is `importScripts`?

Comment: The firebase service worker is a client side script that sits at the root of the entire project. I'm following the docs on firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_service_worker

Comment: any update on this??